# How can I check the total gas used by a transaction?

Tags: web3js, gas

I am trying to figure out the total gas used by a transaction. It appears `gasUsed` = `cumulativeGasUsed` but both values don't check out with the following check:

```
gasPrice = 100000000000
Number(currentBalance) == Number(previousBalance) + amount - (gasUsed * gasPrice)
```

In fact, it's off by 10000. My best guess is the internal `.transfer` call throws off the `gasUsed` value.

Comment: Hey @nickjm, I ran into the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?